# Deciphering HCI event from BLUEnrg-ms bluetooth device

Tags: stm32, hci, bluenrg

I am successfully able to communicate with my IDB05A1 from my nucleo-64 board.

I make it discoverable and pair my phone to it. However immediately after pairing, the device disconnects from my phone.
Before it disconnects I receive a HCI event i cannot decipher:

0x04 0xff 0x0b 0x01 0x0c 0x01 0x08 0x04 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00

please help me decipher this. [datasheet with commands and events](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/6d/a1/5b/6c/dc/ab/48/76/DM00162667.pdf/files/DM00162667.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00162667.pdf)

```
0x04        //HCI event
0xff        //Vendor specific
0x0b        //Contains 0b(12) bytes
0x01, 0x0c  //BLUEnrg event code
0x......
```

What event is this?

Answer (score 0):

This event looks not related to the problem.
It indicates the modified value of some attribute.

HCI event packet:

`0x04    //HCI event
0xff    //Vendor specific
0x0b    //Contains 0b(11) bytes
0x01 0x0c 0x01 0x08 0x04 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00     //Event data`

Event data:

`0x0c01  //ACI_GATT_ATTRIBUTE_MODIFIED_EVENT
0x0801  //The connection handle which modified the attribute
0x0004  //Handle of the attribute that was modified
0x0002  //Length of the attribute data
0x00    //Offset
0x0002  //The modified value`